# Quantum canonical transformation which exchanges $q$ and $p$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, commutator

In classical mechanics, there is a canonical transformation which exchanges $q\to Q=p$ and $p\to P=-q$, generated by $F(q,Q)=qQ$. I'm curious if there is an analogous canonical transformation in the quantum language? Presumably it can be represented as a similarity transformation (which preserves the canonical commutation relations)

$$SqS^{-1}=p,\quad SpS^{-1}=-q$$

What is $S$?

Comment: $S$ is the Fourier-Plancherel transform.

Comment: I believe you, but could you show this explicitly in an answer?